# Inner working of lambda functions when wrapper function is called recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, generic-lambda

Consider the following code:

```
int foo() {
    int lf = [/*captures*/]() {/*body*/};
    if(/*some condition*/) { return /*value*/; }
    foo();    //recursive call
}
```

Now, in this code, whenever the function `foo` is called recursively, an `activation record` of `foo`
will be pushed on to the stack. What I was wondering about is that, is the lambda function included in the record with its definition? Umm..[this](https://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/lambdas.html) ain't helping

Comment: A minor issue with your code: you can't assign lambda to an `int` variable.

Comment: Yeah right. Sorry. Totally forgot that.

Comment: please dont fix your code after you got answers, I rolled back your edit, because otherwise the answers starts with non-sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly:

```
int lf = [/*captures*/]() {/*body*/};
```

is incorrect code, it should be

```
// case 1. lambda is automatic
auto lf = [/*captures*/]() {/*body*/}; // closure object
```

or  (provided that lambda returns something compatible to `int`)

```
// case 2. lambda is temporary
int lf = [/*captures*/]() {/*body*/} (); /* calling object created */
```

lambda expression is a shorthand notation for creation of  object with a unique class
(very simplified, you have to look in standard or in language reference for full description):

```
class Closure {
    /* members storing captured values or references */ 
public:
    return-type  operator( /* argument list*/ ) { /*body*/ };
}
```

In first case lambda would be stored in stack, in second case it is a temporary object.

So lambda with a capture list would store such object, i.e. all captured values exactly where you instructed it to store lambda object, in your case it's automatic storage (so called, "stack"). Using a capture-less lambda is no different from declaring a function and using a pointer to it, there is no storage associated with it and it can be casted to a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The lambda is stored in a local variable of `foo()`, so yes. Each call to `foo()` instantiates a new lambda that is not destroyed until `foo()` exits.

A lambda is just syntax sugar for a compiler-defined type that implements `operator()`. So your example is *roughly* equivalent to this:

```cpp
struct functor{
    /*captures*/
    void operator()() const {/*body*/}
};

int foo() {
    functor lf{/*captures*/};
    if(/*some condition*/) { return /*value*/; }
    foo(); //recursive call
}
```

Comment: From what I know, it is a bit compiler defined too. Some compilers create a copy of the lambda function in a different location, simply call it using the address and only add the variables into the activation record.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 tit's a function. function is not an object by C++ definition,  so compiler\program can't really generate new instructions in memory each time, and what happens is what falls under definition for creation of new automatic storage belonging to a callable object. Now lambda  expression creates NOT function, but an object of unique type, its uniqueness defined by context it was created in.  Regardless how many times recursion had happen it is same context,unless it's a recursive template.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Then  it's possible that each instance of template could own lambda created in compile time, but in fact it's just instance of a new `operator()` - generic lambda's case.